# find result based on one value from previous query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
game_id | score
---------------
1       | 500
2       | 1000
3       | 1500
```

Now, given a `game_id`, I want to get how many other games have a lower score in a single query.

So, when `game_id` = 1, I want `2`as a result.

I instinctively want to run a query to retrieve the `score` of `game_id` = 1 first, then run a simple `select count(*) where...`, but I'm not sure how that is done.

I'm using postgres 9.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can basically just use a subquery on your where clause and pass the game_id inside that subquery, just like this:

```
select count (game_id) from table where score < (select score from table where game_id = 1)
```

The logic behind this is that the engine will evaluate the inner select, return a single value as a result, and then evaluate the outer select using said value

Comment: btw, im assuming your table is called "table" so you might want to change that.